# Can anyone help me with this code? I need to convert it to rails 4 but I don't know how..(routes.rb file from rails 2 to rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do

  map.resources :users, :sent

  map.resources :mailbox, :collection => { :trash => :get }

  map.resources :messages, :member => { :reply => :get, :forward => :get, :reply_all => :get, :undelete => :put }

  map.resource :session

  map.inbox '', :controller => "mailbox", :action => "index"

  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'

  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'

end
```

Comment: I always get this error:  Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/"

Comment: It would be very useful if you showed us what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is this:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do
  root to: "mailbox#index"

  resources :users
  resources :sent

  resources :mailbox do
    collection do
      get :trash
    end
  end

  resources :messages do
    member do
      get :reply
      get :forward
      put :undelete
    end
  end

  resource :session
end
```

The two `connect` routing definitions are no longer used in Rails, as they make *all* actions of *all* controllers available as `GET` requests. For instance, `GET /users/1/destroy`. If you find routes that that used to work are no longer working, you will need to define new routes in `config/routes.rb` for them.